# 404 Error using Flash Builder 4 BlazeDS wizard

Tags: apache-flex, flash, blazeds

My issue this time around is trying to use the new DCD BlazeDS wizard in Flash Builder 4. If I set my project up as a combined Java/Flex app I am unable to connect to the RDS servlet using the wizard. I get a 404 error every time.

I'm certain the service is set up correctly since my app can access the exposed java classes and BlazeMonster can see the exposed services.

Is anyone else having this issue and if so has anyone found a work-around? I'd very much like to use the code generation features of the wizard for my project.

Thanks as always,

Codeflayer

Comment: Seen this problem on windows with ntlm authentication.  Are you on windows and/or running thro iis?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure you have the RDSDispatchServlet setup in the web.xml config file.

Comment: Thanks but the web.xml file is set up correctly (to my knowledge)

<servlet>
<servlet-name>RDSDispatchServlet</servlet-name>
<display-name>RDSDispatchServlet</display-name>
<servlet-class>flex.rds.server.servlet.FrontEndServlet</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>useAppserverSecurity</param-name>
<param-value>false</param-value>
</init-param>
<load-on-startup>10</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping id="RDS_DISPATCH_MAPPING">
<servlet-name>RDSDispatchServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/CFIDE/main/ide.cfm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>